# jquery appended objects all have the same left value

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a javascript/jquery code
It appends a bunch of span elements to the main div container and then animates them to move to the left. I need to be able to detect the left value of each span element, however when I output the left value to the console log it shows that they all have the same value. any ideas?

http://jsbin.com/uKobuja/2/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: I get an error: `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null "`

Comment: What do you expect the "left" value to be? You're setting them all to be `-10px` when you animate, so it is reasonable that they all print out the same value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is this: http://jsbin.com/uKobuja/11/edit

```
$(this).offset().left
```

instead of

```
this.style.left
```

That is because your spans are relatively positioned. All of them will have the same left css value

Comment: I think this is right, but they also might be looking for `$(this).position().left`, depending on what they're doing.

Answer (score 1):

i see your js feedle code to see all span apply

```
       console.log($(this).offset().left);
```